# Why does RStudio calls a random generator during View?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using RStudio 0.99.467 with R 3.2.2 on a Mac, and I noticed that `View` calls the random number generator, or something like that. Here are the codes:

```
set.seed(1) # not needed when I run it on RStudio, but needed on R
rs <- .Random.seed
cat(76 + 8)
all(.Random.seed == rs)
# TRUE  -- because a simple function shouldn't change the random numbers
View(3)
all(.Random.seed == rs)
# FALSE -- ???
```

Actually, the only difference is in the second number of `.Random.seed`

```
all((.Random.seed == rs)[-2])
# TRUE
```

which seems to increase in 10 units always

```
.Random.seed[2] - rs[2]
# 10
```

Is that the expected behaviour of the `View` function or is a bug in the version that I'm running only?

Comment: Your code doesn't work as `.Random.seed` is not defined by default. You need at least a `set.seed()` first.

Comment: With your edit, you show an interesting thing. RStudio already has a `.Random.seed` set, which is not the case in console R. So my previous comment is incorrect in your case.

Comment: Although, I cannot reproduce this on a previous version of RStudio (0.98.1103) running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Update to my previous comment. I can reproduce this with RStudio version `0.99.878`

Comment: Not really active around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed expected. RStudio's data viewer in 0.99 generates random cache keys for your data using the R `sample` function. The data viewer in 0.98 didn't do this (it just generated raw HTML).

I've just logged an issue for us to look at removing this side effect in a future release (I agree it's unexpected that viewing data changes your random seed).

Comment: Is there a way to create a function to go around that problem meanwhile?

Comment: Yes, you can save the random seed beforehand and restore it afterwards (see `set.seed`). Incidentally we've just fixed the issue in RStudio itself, so it'll be in the next daily build (0.99.1081 or newer) if you want to try it.